# Interaction between two intents in an alexa skill using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit

I have two intents, first collects the name and the second collects the phone number. What I want to do is I want to restrict the user to first add the name and only then add the phone number. If the user tries to add the phone number first, the skill should ask to input the name first.  I am implementing the skill using python.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in the request handler an additional condition other than the intent name, using, for example, the [session](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/manage-skill-session-and-session-attributes.html).

Starting from [this](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/handle-requests.html#request-handlers) you have to add that check in the method `can_handle` if you are using classes, or add a proper `can_handle_func` when using decorators